# Can i create a function inside a function in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

If I can create a function then how do I call it from another function in the same controller,
I have created a function which gets data from a form like to,cc,bcc, subject etc .They are part of a form and another form which gets attachments from the function in which I get attachments. I want to call a function which is getting the other details so i can send a email.

function emaildata()

{
  //here it fetches details like subject message

```
   function Sendmail($attachments)
      {
          //send your mail

       }
```

}

function getattachments()
  {

//get attachments here

sendmail($attachments);

}

Answer (score 0):

You can call function from same controller! as its Same class.

But try to make it non public function so it won't be accessible form the website ( ex : use _ {underscore} in the beginning of the method name)

Reference here : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#private

Answer (score 0):

You can define private controller function like this (private function names must start with underscore):

```
private function _get_details()
{
  // some code
}
```

it will not be accessible through url, but you can invoke it like this:

```
function send_mail()
{
   //do something
   $this->_get_details();
   // and we called the other method here!
}
```

You can restructure your code like this:

```
public function emaildata()
{
   //here it fetches details like subject message
   $emaildata->subject = "..";
   //get attachments
   $attachments = $this->_getattachments();
   $this->_sendmail($emaildata,$attachments);
}

private function _getattachments() {
   //get attachments here
}

private function _sendmail($emaildata,$attachments)
{
   //send your mail
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. But you can restructure your code.

Comment: data to functions is coming from ajax in my case

Comment: You have two separate forms? First is accepting data, and second is accepting attachments, and the second form is sending email?

Comment: i want to sum up the data and attachments and pass it to another function for sending